# Алгоритмы генерации дорог на местности

Tags: карты, графы

столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Имеется карта, которая задана матрицей высот. На этой карте имеются различные объекты, в том числе и дома. Нужно как-то проложить между ними дороги по кратчайшему пути, но при этом обходя препятствия (сносить их нельзя).
Сколько не искал, не могу найти литературу или статьи. Большинство, я так понял, начинаю создании карты с прокладки дорог, а уже потом раскидывают дома, у меня же обратная задача.
Очень прошу, если кто знает, подсказать названия алгоритмов или (в идеале) литературу по данной теме.

В теории можно было бы использовать алгоритмы поиска кратчайшего пути в графе, но граф у нас в данном случае не существует.
Единственное, что пришло в голову: построить граф со всеми возможными маршрутами. Тупо бежать от точки к точке, если встречается препятствия, то огибать их. Далее ищем к каждой точке кратчайший маршрут и удаляем неиспользуемые ветви, но этот алгоритм явно не самый оптимальный, как мне кажется.

Comment: Вы могли бы пример данных предоставить? Очень сложно понять, например, насколько сильные перепады высот. Если можно чётко понимать: где дом, а где нет на основе какого-нибудь критерия, то граф построить не сложно. Фактически задача, как мне кажется, сводится к качественной детекции препятсвий. Кстати, насколько будет плохо, если мы дорогой заедем на дом? А что, если наоборот: дорогу не проложим в том месте, где она должна бы быть?